# ESP32 board can't compile the ESP8266wifi.h include file

Tags: esp32, esp8266wifi

I use ESP32 board. I want to get the content from google sheet. my reference code is as below
The error was ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory.
Does anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks

```
`#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
 #include "HTTPSRedirect.h"
 const char* ssid = " ";
 const char* password = " ";
 const char* host = "script.google.com";
 const char *GScriptId = "";
 const int httpsPort = 443;
 HTTPSRedirect* client ;
 void setup(){
     WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
     client = new HTTPSRedirect(httpsPort);
     client->setPrintResponseBody(true);
     client->setContentTypeHeader("application/json");
     client->connect(host, httpsPort);
 }
 void loop() {
     String url3 = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?&id=";       
     if (client->GET(url3, host)){
         Serial.println("GET SUCCESS");
     }  
     delay(4000);                          
 }`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building for an ESP32. The ESP32 is not an ESP8266. `ESP8266WiFi.h` is, oddly enough, for the ESP8266, not the ESP32. It's just `WiFi.h` on the ESP32.

Comment: i have tryied the wifi.h. compiler can pass but i can not get the information from google sheet.

Comment: That’s a different problem. You should post that as a new StackOverflow question with details to get help with it.